# Using a function in a join condition, could it cause a full table scans due to the lack of a useable index?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

How can I optimize the performance of a query that contains the following code?

```
FROM members m
JOIN settings s ON MD5(m.ID) = s.ID...
```

Comment: Maybe a computed/derived column 'id_md5' that's already an MD5 of ID that you then index?

Comment: There won't be a problem with the ID. The problem is that the MD5-function is evaluated on every row (RBAR). If you do any heavy lifting in the function it will become slow very fast.

Comment: You are right but for the moment I need to find a solution without adding a new column

Comment: What about a view? Index would be built over calculated value

Comment: You can add and then remove it in the output by grouping or simply omitting the column if it doesn't add rows the final expression.

Comment: What does your MD5 function do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, the only way you can optimize the performance is to put an index on `settings(ID)`.  MySQL should then do a full table scan of the `members` table, with an index lookup in the `settings` table.

You could change the data structure to include the `md5(id)` in the `members` table and then build an index on that value.

Other databases have other capabilities for resolving these queries (notably hash-based join algorithms and functional indexes).  MySQL does not support these capabilities.